# Sequelize add a foreign key column in a table corresponding to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a database structure in which i have 4  tables lets assume to be

Table1, Table2, Table3 and Table4

the relation between table1,2,3 is as follows:

```
(Table1).hasMany(Table2)
(Table2).hasMany(Table3)
```

now there is another table Table4 which has a key references which is a foreignkey for either table1,table2,table3 ie the table would look like something like this

```
Table4

+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               references          |    Col2    | Col3   |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| foreign key Table1                | value1     | random |
| foreign key Table1                | value2     | random |
| foreign key Table2                | value2     | random |
| foreign key Table3                | value3     | random |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

how do I define the relationship between the tables. In the doc there is no such usecase mentioned. Is there a particular way to go about it? Or show I store the data without defining the foreign key relationship?

Comment: `foreignkey for either table1,table2,table3` sounds like you need a super table and uuids

Comment: Any update here?